# Form won't submit

Tags: php, javascript, forms

I have form below which won't submit to my email. I have pasted my form code, javascript and php code below. I am a newbie in javascript and please assist.

```
<form id="form-main" action="bin/bookHandler.php">
                                    .


                                            <div class="clear"></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="row1">Additional Comments:</div>
                                        <label class="message">
                                            <textarea></textarea>
                                        </label>
                                        <div class="clear"></div>
                                        <div class="buttons">
                                            <a onClick="document.getElementById('form-main').submit()">Send</a>
                                            <a onClick="document.getElementById('form-main').reset()">Clear</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </fieldset>
                                </form>
```

Below is the javascript for the form:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.extend({
        forms:function(opt){
            if(opt===undefined)
                opt={}
            this.each(function(){
                var th=$(this),
                    data=th.data('forms'),
                    _={
                        errorCl:'error',
                        emptyCl:'empty',
                        invalidCl:'invalid',
                        successCl:'success',
                        successShow:'4000',
                        mailHandlerURL:'bin/MailHandler.php',
                        ownerEmail:'username@gmail.com',
                        stripHTML:true,
                        smtpMailServer:'localhost',
                        targets:'input,textarea',
                        controls:'a[data-type=reset],a[data-type=submit]',
                        validate:true,
                        rx:{
                            ".name":{rx:/^[a-zA-Z'][a-zA-Z-' ]+[a-zA-Z']?$/,target:'input'},
                            ".state":{rx:/^[a-zA-Z'][a-zA-Z-' ]+[a-zA-Z']?$/,target:'input'},
                            ".email":{rx:/^(("[\w-\s]+")|([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)|("[\w-\s]+")([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*))(@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$)|(@\[?((25[0-5]\.|2[0-4][0-9]\.|1[0-9]{2}\.|[0-9]{1,2}\.))((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\.){2}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\]?$)/i,target:'input'},
                            ".phone":{rx:/^\+?(\d[\d\-\+\(\) ]{5,}\d$)/,target:'input'},
                            ".fax":{rx:/^\+?(\d[\d\-\+\(\) ]{5,}\d$)/,target:'input'},
                            ".message":{rx:/.{20}/,target:'textarea'}
                        },
                        preFu:function(){
                            _.labels.each(function(){
                                var label=$(this),
                                    inp=$(_.targets,this),
                                    defVal=inp.val(),
                                    trueVal=(function(){
                                                var tmp=inp.is('input')?(tmp=label.html().match(/value=['"](.+?)['"].+/),!!tmp&&!!tmp[1]&&tmp[1]):inp.html()
                                                return defVal==''?defVal:tmp
                                            })()
                                trueVal!=defVal
                                    &&inp.val(defVal=trueVal||defVal)
                                label.data({defVal:defVal})                             
                                inp
                                    .bind('focus',function(){
                                        inp.val()==defVal
                                            &&(inp.val(''),_.hideEmptyFu(label),label.removeClass(_.invalidCl))
                                    })
                                    .bind('blur',function(){
                                        !inp.val()
                                            ?inp.val(defVal)                                        
                                            :(_.isValid(label)
                                                ?_.showErrorFu(label)
                                                :_.hideErrorFu(label)),
                                            (_.isEmpty(label)
                                                ?_.showEmptyFu(label)
                                                :_.hideEmptyFu(label))
                                    })
                                    .bind('keyup',function(){
                                        label.hasClass(_.invalidCl)
                                            &&_.isValid(label)
                                                ?_.showErrorFu(label)
                                                :_.hideErrorFu(label)
                                    })
                                label.find('.'+_.errorCl+',.'+_.emptyCl).css({display:'block'}).hide()
                            })
                            _.success=$('.'+_.successCl,_.form).hide()
                        },
                        isValid:function(el){
                            var ret=true,
                                empt=_.isEmpty(el)
                            if(empt)
                                ret=false,
                                el.addClass(_.invalidCl)
                            else
                                $.each(_.rx,function(k,d){
                                    if(el.is(k))
                                        d.rx.test(el.find(d.target).val())
                                            ?(el.removeClass(_.invalidCl),ret=false)
                                            :el.addClass(_.invalidCl)
                                })
                            return ret
                        },
                        isEmpty:function(el){
                            var tmp
                            return (tmp=el.find(_.targets).val())==''||tmp==el.data('defVal')
                        },
                        validateFu:function(){                          
                            _.labels.each(function(){
                                var th=$(this)                              
                                _.isEmpty(th)
                                    ?_.showEmptyFu(th)
                                    :_.hideEmptyFu(th)
                                _.isValid(th)
                                    ?_.showErrorFu(th)
                                    :_.hideErrorFu(th)
                            })
                        },
                        submitFu:function(){
                            _.validateFu()
                            if(!_.form.has('.'+_.invalidCl).length)
                                $.ajax({
                                    type: "POST",
                                    url:_.mailHandlerURL,
                                    data:{
                                        name:$('.name input',_.form).val()||'nope',
                                        email:$('.email input',_.form).val()||'nope',
                                        phone:$('.phone input',_.form).val()||'nope',
                                        fax:$('.fax input',_.form).val()||'nope',
                                        state:$('.state input',_.form).val()||'nope',
                                        message:$('.message textarea',_.form).val()||'nope',
                                        owner_email:_.ownerEmail,
                                        stripHTML:_.stripHTML
                                    },
                                    success: function(){
                                        _.showFu()
                                    }
                                })          
                        },
                        showFu:function(){
                            _.success.slideDown(function(){
                                setTimeout(function(){
                                    _.success.slideUp()
                                    _.form.trigger('reset')
                                },_.successShow)
                            })
                        },
                        controlsFu:function(){
                            $(_.controls,_.form).each(function(){
                                var th=$(this)
                                th
                                    .bind('click',function(){
                                        _.form.trigger(th.data('type'))
                                        return false
                                    })
                            })
                        },
                        showErrorFu:function(label){
                            label.find('.'+_.errorCl).slideDown()
                        },
                        hideErrorFu:function(label){
                            label.find('.'+_.errorCl).slideUp()
                        },
                        showEmptyFu:function(label){
                            label.find('.'+_.emptyCl).slideDown()
                            _.hideErrorFu(label)
                        },
                        hideEmptyFu:function(label){
                            label.find('.'+_.emptyCl).slideUp()
                        },
                        init:function(){
                            _.form=this
                            _.labels=$('label',_.form)

                            _.preFu()

                            _.controlsFu()

                            _.form
                                .bind('submit',function(){
                                    if(_.validate)
                                        _.submitFu()
                                    else
                                        _.form[0].submit()
                                    return false
                                })
                                .bind('reset',function(){
                                    _.labels.removeClass(_.invalidCl)                                   
                                    _.labels.each(function(){
                                        var th=$(this)
                                        _.hideErrorFu(th)
                                        _.hideEmptyFu(th)
                                    })
                                })
                            _.form.trigger('reset')
                        }
                    }
                if(!data)
                    (typeof opt=='object'?$.extend(_,opt):_).init.call(th),
                    th.data({cScroll:_}),
                    data=_
                else
                    _=typeof opt=='object'?$.extend(data,opt):data
            })
            return this
        }
    })
})(jQuery)

$(function(){
   $('#contact-form').forms({
     ownerEmail:'username@gmail.com'
     })
})
```

Below is the php:

```
<?php
$field_name = $_POST["cf_name"];
$field_email = $_POST["cf_email"];
$field_tel = $_POST["tel"];
$field_stay = $_POST["selectStay"];
$field_people = $_POST["selectPeople"];
$field_month = $_POST["selectMonth"];
$field_day = $_POST["selectDay"];
$field_year = $_POST["selectYear"];
$field_message = $_POST["cf_message"];

$mail_to = 'username@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Message from a site visitor '.$field_name;

$body_message = 'From: '.$field_name."\n";
$body_message .= 'E-mail: '.$field_email."\n";
$body_message .= 'Telephone/Cell: '.$field_tel."\n";
$body_message .= 'Length of stay: '.$field_stay."\n";
$body_message .= 'Number of people: '.$field_people."\n";
$body_message .= 'Month: '.$field_month.;
$body_message .= 'Day: '.$field_day.;
$body_message .= 'Year: '.$field_year."\n";
$body_message .= 'Message: '.$field_message;

$headers = 'From: '.$field_email."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n";

$mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

if ($mail_status) { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Thank you for the message. We will contact you shortly.');

    </script>
<?php
}
else { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Message failed. Please, send an email to ssssss');

    </script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: what happens when you try to submit? nothing? error?

Comment: Perhaps you could thin out the code so what we have here is the smallest possible piece that still causes the problem. (While doing that you will be quite likely to find the problem yourself.)

Comment: @Maziar Bouali Where should I use lowercase?

Comment: @aniri When I submit it does as if submitted but no form details come to my inbox.

Comment: try using firebug for firefox or developer tools from google or something similar to check for errors. also, try printing some values after the POST to make sure that worked and the values are stored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at print_r($_POST);
Is the POST successful?

Comment: @aniri On my URL it has http://www.vvvvv.com/bin/bookHandler.php?select=2&select=2&select=April&select=Day&select=Year. Nothing is printed